# List items won't align/inherit img/div size

Tags: css, alignment, css-position

I'm trying to create a list of text that sits directly underneath an image. The image is loaded via a CMS and may be of any size. so I can't think of a way to use fixed dimensions.

Does this make sense?

Here is my code:
currently they (the list items) align to the far left of the div the ul is placed in.

**css**

```
.maincontent h5 {
    font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
    font-weight:600;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-indent:2px;
    text-align:left;
    line-height:0px;
}
.maincontent img {
    max-width:900px;
    text-align:center;
    display: block; 
margin-left: auto; 
margin-right: auto;
}
.maincontent a {
    text-decoration:none;
}
.maincontent a:hover {
}
.maincontent ul {
    display:block;
    list-style-type:none;
    list-style:none;
    z-index:5;
    padding:0px;
}

.maincontent ul li {
    display:block;
    text-align:left;
    list-style-type:none;
    list-style:none;
}
```

**html**

```
 <div style="display:block; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;"><ul>

    <li>
    <img src="/americanmedium1/files/9913/3401/0984/AM-LOGO.jpg" width="300" height="111"    alt="" />
    </li>

    <li><h5>testes</h5></li>

    <li><h5>setsete</h5></li>

    <li><h5>setes</h5></li>

    <li><h5>estes</h5></li>

    <li><h5>estes</h5></li>

    <li><h5>setes</h5></li>

</ul></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

your issue is you're setting the UL to be `display: block;` which pushes it to 100% width of the container it is in.. if the container it is in is wider than the image the list will appear off. I've attempted to [mock something up](http://jsfiddle.net/rlemon/DSMbS/) using your code but it is clear we're missing some of the HTML. Try setting the UL width, or setting it to 'inline-block'